# Is the control given by Pontryagin's Minimum Principle suboptimal?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, control-theory, nonlinear-system, optimal-control

I'm studying nonlinear control systems and I have some questions about the nature of this optimal control given by PMP:

- Traditionally, control methods based on Pontryagin's Minimum Principle (PMP) and Euler's method (or Runge Kutta) have been extensively used to address nonlinear system control problems. Is there a potential to get trapped in local minima resulting in suboptimal control outcomes?
- If there is one, why do we call it "optimal"?

Comment: A local optimum is still an optimum, isn't it?

Comment: PMP is optimal. However, finding the optimal solution, given the correct initial conditions for the co-state, such that the desired terminal conditions are met can be hard (otherwise one obtained an optimal solution to a different optimal control problem). However, if the desired terminal conditions are met then you did find the relevant solution to your optimal control problem.